# What is the best way to forcefully say each word in a sentence.

Tags: punctuation, sentence

Here is the example that I have:

> "Mother," I said with clenched teeth, "I said I don't want to talk
>   about it."

Now,

I'd like to express the fact that each word in the second part of the sentence is said with a hard break or pause. Example:

> "I. said. I. don't. want. to. talk. about. it."

I'm sure there is a better way, so any help would be appreciated. Also, what is this type of pause called?

Comment: There is a http://writers.stackexchange.com that might provide you with more ideas too.

Comment: [Best. Question. Ever.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DARTHWIKI/DETHRONINGMOMENTOFSUCK) (Thanks to _The Simpsons_, I've seen this speech construct represented with single-word sentences.)

Comment: Actually, you are almost there: "I-said-I-don't-want-to-talk-about-it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some judicious italics:

"Mother," I said with clenched teeth, "I said *I don't want to talk about it.*"

Comment: Yup. Or **boldface** or ***both***. Or. Periods. And. Capitals. Or ALL CAPS (though that's shouting, not clenched-teeth). Writing is creative technology; channel and chop that sentence till you get what **you** want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convey it through typing characters, I would write:

> "Mother", I said with clenched teeth, word by word/stressing each word, "I said I don't want to talk about it."

Then again, there are other ways such as the ones mentioned above.